# Android bluetooth low energy (ble) writeCharacteristic delay callback

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am implementing a application on Android using BLE Api (SDK 18), and I have a issue that the transfer data process is delay very slow. This is my log.

> 03-12 16:20:05.121: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: ...
>
> 03-12 16:20:06.272: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=... UUID=... Status=0
>
> 03-12 16:20:06.972: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: ...
>
> 03-12 16:20:08.254: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=... UUID=... Status=0
>
> 03-12 16:20:10.055: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: ...
>
> 03-12 16:20:11.257: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=... UUID=... Status=0
>
> 03-12 16:20:12.478: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: ...
>
> 03-12 16:20:14.250: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=... UUID=... Status=0
>
> 03-12 16:20:14.960: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: ...
>
> 03-12 16:20:16.242: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=... UUID=... Status=0
>
> 03-12 16:20:16.402: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: ...
>
> 03-12 16:20:20.225: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=... UUID=... Status=0
>
> 03-12 16:20:20.526: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: ...
>
> 03-12 16:20:24.219: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=... UUID=... Status=0
>
> 03-12 16:20:25.360: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: ...
>
> 03-12 16:20:27.222: D/BluetoothGatt(13578): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=... UUID=... Status=0

For more information, I found that every Transfer Progress only completes when it has the onCharacteristicWrite callback, this means that all sending command before receive  onCharacteristicWrite callback will be ignored.

Is this the flow of Android we have to following or there is any way to setup it skip the callback step to speed up the progress.

My code is:

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
......
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    mSending = false;
}
};

private void writeCharacteristic() {
    .....

    mGattCharacSetIntensity.setValue(data);
    mGattCharacSetIntensity.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mGattCharacSetIntensity);
    return;
}
```

EDIT: I have a comparison with iPhone (a BLE transfer data app from AppStore), the BLE transfer data is very quick (less than 0.5 sec), so impressive. How can we work around to SPEED UP the Android BLE Transfer progress?.

EDIT: If I set WriteType of BluetoothGattCharacteristic to WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE, and when I send many command sequentially, the Android stores them on a queue and send to remote device one by one after receive writeCharacteristic CallBack, this leads to a issue, when you stop your sending lood, the Android Sending Progress still continue with the delay (Sometime more than 3 sec).

Comment: Is this the output of emulated bluetooth or real values from your device?

Comment: These are from real Nexus 7, version 2013, Android OS 4.3

Comment: Actually Android BLE stack works synchronously. So its works stack wise operations.

Comment: Thank user370305, I agree with you, but there is not any document form Google Android to confirm about that. so I do not have any evidence. So sad. Can we decrease the delay interval?

Comment: Your writes should definitely not be taking so long. On a KitKat device my performance tests showed that I was able to write at more than 7KB/s and crossing 10 with responses turned off. Every write was done only after a response was received from the bluetooth device.

Comment: Thank Zomb, the issue is if your send many commands sequentially, the delay between two commands will be so long, more than expectation.

Answer (score 5):

Performance of a BLE link is highly dependent on the connection interval used, and if your connection interval is high, the performance you see may not be that unreasonable. By the Core Specification, the connection interval can be between 7.5 ms and 4 s, so there's quite some flexibility.

If it's possible for you, I'd recommend you to try changing the Peripheral you're talking to to use a shorter connection interval, which should improve performance. You may have use in taking a look at [this page](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/index.php/how-do-i-calculate-throughput-for-a-ble-link), explaining BLE throughput, and [this page](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/index.php/what-is-connection-parameters), explaining connection parameters.

Comment: Thank @hlnd, I am try your suggestion.

Comment: Dear hlnd, Your links just said that the connection quality depends on OS, but how can we make it more faster on Android (4.3), I expectation is less than 1 sec.

Comment: As I said, you'll probably have to change the code running on the Peripheral side to request a shorter connection interval as soon as possible after connection have been established. Exactly how to do this will be highly dependent on which chip you use on this device, so I can't really comment on that here.

Comment: Dear hind, it is unfortunately, the Peripheral side is out of my scope, this is the Device from customer. I cannot do any to optimize this side.

Comment: In that case I don't really have any suggestions. As far as I know, it's not possible to change connection parameters from the Android side.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem. It occurs after several writes and goes away when you reconnect the Gatt. What we do is measure the delay between writeCharacteristic() and onCharacteristicWrite(). If it is above a certain threshold (1500ms), we disconnect() and close() the gatt server and reconnect. After that it is usually fine for a while.

When doing this it might become necessary to disable the whole bluetooth adapter and reenable it. Otherwise the first reconnect to the gatt server fails and it takes about 15 seconds until it is reconnected. Sometimes it never reconnects.

When disabling the adapter you might run into the problem that service discovery does not return in onServicesDiscovered(). We have currently no solution for that.

Comment: Hope the next Android Version will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem for me as well. If you delay the calls in the debugger you can confirm that there is a delay when writing to BLE radios. I will be implementing a queue in my application to handle the latency.

Here is what I do for queueing up commands:

```
public void sendWriteCommandToConnectedMachine(byte[] commandByte) {
    if(commandByte.length > 20)
        dissectAndSendCommandBytes(commandByte);
    else
        queueCommand(commandByte); //TODO - need to figure out if service is valid or not
}

private void queueCommand(byte[] command) {
    mCommandQueue.add(command);

    if(!mWaitingCommandResponse)
        dequeCommand();
}
```

Hereis what I do for dequeuing BLE commands

```
private void dequeCommand() {
    if(mCommandQueue.size() > 0) {
        byte[] command = mCommandQueue.get(0);
        mCommandQueue.remove(0);
        sendWriteCommand(command);
    }
}
```

here is my characteristic write method

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if(status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
            logMachineResponse(characteristic, status);     

        mWaitingCommandResponse = false;
        dequeCommand();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement you're own flow control, don't start a write until the OnCharacteristicWrite is sent for the previous write