# Delay between WriteCharacteristic and callback onCharacteristicWrite

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send several segments of data over a Bluetooth Low Energy connection. As I read in this post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562847/samsung-android-ble-multiple-read-write?rq=1)) no further data will be sent until the onCharacteristicWrite callback has been fired. I have confirmed this but the callback is not fired until about **3** seconds after I write to the characteristic and this is slowing down my application. I know that the data has arrived since I am monitoring the blueooth module with an FTDI-cable.

I have tried to change the connection interval as suggested in this post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348470/android-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-writecharacteristic-delay-callback))  and also reduced the Slave Latency but nothing changed.

Why is this happening and how can I reduce this this time between writeCharacteristic and OnCharacteristicWrite?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the device response is return too late to android.
"write type" default value is **"BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT"**.

Solution is you should change this to **"BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE"** for don't wait for response from device:

`bluetoothGattCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);`

is speed up your **onCharacteristicWrite()** callback duration of trigger.